ZustandJS and React Router with Initial call renders twice
currently I am struggeling with React Router & ZustandJS.
I like to use a Store to save a part of the path of the current location. Like Test/Test123/. And and as soon Test123 will change to Test124 useEffect should fire an action(fetch) which is gonna update the store after success. But with the current Code it triggers twice. Even if the value will be same as before. I guess its because react router remounts the Compontent. How to handle this issue without using useRef to the previous value?
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/zustand-router-problem-double-render-27q4t2
I tried already to fix it with use ref and surely it will work. But this would mean I have to check all the time the previous variable...

Are you using React.StrictMode?

No, as shown in the sandbox

Do you mean that when you switch path's it prints c1 and then c2??
when click the same path again, nothing is printed

UseEffekt triggers two times on the first visit. I like to do a fetch here. How I can prevent the frist executation?
